# no such table Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with Django. I got the Error Message: no such table: **tablename**. I already defined the model and now I want to safe Data in this model. But it cannot find the table. I hope you can help me.

```
#my models.py

class ImageUpload(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField(upload_to= user_directory_path)
    camera = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

#my view.py

if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            camera = form.cleaned_data['camera']
       

            uploaded_file = ImageUpload(
                image=image,
                camera=camera,
            )

            uploaded_file.save()
```

Comment: Did you apply the [migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/migrations/) to create the table in the database?

Comment: Yes, I already used manage.py migrate and makemigrations

Comment: Django doesn't lie to you (as far as I know). Can you use database tools to check the structure of the database? BTW, which database do you use?

Comment: Are you using multiple databases ? If yes you need to define which database to use with the help of `using`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot this issue you can manually check, if querying your model is possible:

```
./manage.py shell
from appname.models import ImageUpload
ImageUpload.objects.all()
```

Also it will be more clear if you will show us your generated migration containing this DB change. Also please provide full code for your view.